# Should transaction id's skip?

Tags: mysql, transaction

In my application, the transaction id's sometimes skip i.e. 3314, 3315, 3317 ... I think this happens when a payment is made, but mysql rolls back the transaction because of an error down the line.

I was perfectly fine with this.

However, an accountant working in a company that uses my application said the id's should not skip - he feels uncomfortable with it. I suppose it feels to him like there are missing records. He said he has never seen that in any application before.

Is that a rare thing (the skipping) - something I should try to fix - (I actually don't think so), or it is not unusual and there is a way to explain that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Database keys should not be conflated with business identifiers like invoice numbers or transaction numbers, unless their semantics are **identical.**

The reason you have an ID field in a database is to provide a unique, irrevocable identifier for a record.  If that record happens to get removed from the database, the ID for that record is **never reused** (for what I hope are obvious reasons).

If a *requirement* of the business is that there be no gaps in transaction numbers, then put another field in the database that maintains transaction numbers separately, so that you can adhere to the business rules without touching your database IDs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it is very difficult to agree on what precisely the semantics of a value is supposed to be. The transaction ID in your system is presumably specified as a unique integer value, maybe even a "four-digit number" or something like that. But in practice it is impossible to implement a specification like this without additional regularity arising, which people then notice and assume to be part of the specification.

For instance, a simple way to ensure uniqueness is to generate monotonically increasing values. This probably isn't required by the specs - you could return any of the uncounted numbers of possible permutations of the number space that your system allows. But it's way easier to remember a single counter than to remember all IDs that are already in use. And to conserve space, it makes sense to count upwards in steps of 1.

However, emitting numbers increasing by 1 looks exactly as if you were counting the events that have happened. Even if the values aren't supposed to be running numbers, once people get the idea that they *are* running numbers, they will complain if they spot what they think is a "wrong" value. This isn't something that people can help - spotting patterns and drawing conclusions from them is what we do, and we can't stop doing it any more than we can stop focusing on a red apple in a display full of green ones.

Now for the question: should you change your system to conform to the inevitable but wrong assumptions that people are going to make?

And the answer, as usual, is "It's a trade-off". If avoiding surprises gains you more in user acceptance and improved compliance by the operators than it costs to implement, then do it. For instance, maybe you could add logic that rewrites transaction IDs after the fact or take over ID assignment altogether from the database engine. A cheap way of signalling that IDs aren't running numbers is to start at a large value so that people realise "We can't possibly have built 9448376987 cars". More sophisticated would be to transform IDs with a bijective but complex function so that the values *look* random although they are in fact predictable. Choose the method that doesn't cost more than people's acceptance of the system's behaviour is worth in your context.

Comment: Speaking practically, if we assume these two user requirements: 1) the id's do not skip 2) the transaction time for every id, is less than that for any greater id so that t1.id > t2.id always means t1.timestamp >= t2.timestamp . I doubt it is possible to achieve both in a concurrent system of any substantial complexity, especially if it interfaces (in real time) with any external systems where the id is part of the interface.

Comment: @Emmanuel: ACID databases are very good at this kind of concurrency.  Not sure what you mean about the timestamps; in practice, a monotonically increasing ID is always going to have a timestamp greater than the one before it.  Of course, that presumes that you don't re-use any ID's, which is why your problem exists in the first place.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Here's what I meant: alluding to what Kilian wrote about the possibility of rewriting the transaction id after the transaction, or handling the id generation outside the db, I don't see how a system can 'non-trivially' achieve BOTH A.ids not skipping B. making sure every new id is greater than already assigned ids. Achieving B, would mean that you don't recycle ids that were used in failed transactions (which were rolled back) because, before the rollback, another transaction may have 'picked' the next id. Ergo, it is not possible IMHO to achieve both.

Comment: @Emmanuel: Yes, you're right about that.  This is the same problem accountants have with invoice numbers that aren't continuous.  It's kind of silly, really, given that you can void a check and lose that check number.

Comment: @Emmanuel: And if something goes wrong with an invoice in a system, it never makes sense to recycle the ID, because you need that ID if you ever want to look back at what happened.  For that reason (and to satisfy the bean counters), invoice numbers are often maintained as a separate field in the database from the IDs.